# ExactTarget - add to SF SE, or spin up a new SE?

Tags: discussion

As the Salesforce Platform expands, the question arises - should Salesforce StackExchange also expand its scope? For example, ExactTarget is now the [ExactTarget Marketing Cloud](http://www.salesforce.com/marketing-cloud/overview/) - should ExactTarget users feel free to ask questions here?

Personally, I think the answer should be 'yes'. There is, apparently, a large overlap in the user bases, and one bigger Q&A seems better than two smaller sites. The overlap means that a user here to ask an ExactTarget question might notice a 'classic' Salesforce question they can answer.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes, for sure metadaddy!

Comment: I say yes, but with the caveat that the Exact Target posts should be "policed" and tagged with an exacttarget tag, so that we can distinguish ET posts vs. Force.com, etc posts.

Answer (score 22):

I say yes. This site isn't overwhelmed with traffic and questions as is, so the added "clutter" seems manageable to me.

The added scope seems well within bounds to me.

Comment: I think there'd be a reasonable amount of overlap that would only increase over time as the platforms are more tightly integrated.

Answer (score 15):

I say yes, because I think of this site serving all of their major offerings, including but not limited to:

- Salesforce
- Force.com
- Marketing Cloud
- Data.com

I think it is reasonable for users and developers integrating the various offerings to expect they can find help for all things Salesforce here, in a one-stop shop. We might not have expertise (yet) in Pardot, Exact Target, Radian 6, et al, but I would encourage that growth.

Answer (score 10):

Looks like we're moving in the direction of welcoming those guys on board, so everybody try and avoid closing questions as 'off topic' if they involve some unfamiliar subjects!

Answer (score 9):

Thanks for your help getting this up and running. We will be working on getting some general questions set up that some of you may already know.  I may also answer a few myself to get the ball rolling.  Excited to be a part of everything, even if I am a n00b here.

Comment: welcome on the site  :-)