# Encouraging ExactTarget questions to be tagged

Tags: discussion, exacttarget

From some recent questions it appears that the ExactTarget support forums are now redirecting people here. See [Code@ Questions have Moved!](https://code.exacttarget.com/questions).

> **Code@ Questions have Moved!**
>   In an effort to streamline our efforts, Code@ has moved the Questions and Answers section to the Salesforce StackExchange site, which you can find at the following url: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exacttarget.
>
> We will discontinue support for this section, and will only be monitoring questions at that location. If your question is currently unanswered, feel free to post that same question on StackExchange to the broader community.
>
> Thank you for your understanding!

I have no problem with this ([ref](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/505/exacttarget-add-to-sf-se-or-spin-up-a-new-se)), but it can be confusing if you aren't familiar with ExactTarget that the questions are actually applicable here. Example: [How to use HTTPGet variable in URL](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/27864/how-to-use-httpget-variable-in-url-exacttarget)

Does anyone know who to contact about the code.exacttarget.com page to see if we can get the message updated? It would be great if it could include explicit instructions to tag questions with `exacttarget`.

I did a cursory search of the site and couldn't find a contact us page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah sure. Thanks for the feedback. I'll see about getting it added today. Sorry for the confusion as we work through migration

Comment: Perfect, thanks.

Comment: If I am a Salesforce employee working directly on a product, can I be made a moderator for Salesforce's StackExchange?  We're having a high-rate of question closures recently for the Salesforce Marketing Cloud's MobilePush Android SDK and I have failed to get moderator assistance in getting the questions re-opened :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe Kelly J Andrews (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/4786/kelly-j-andrews) should be able to do this.

I've send him a tweet to come have a look.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: If I am a Salesforce employee working directly on a product, can I be made a moderator for Salesforce's StackExchange?  We're having a high-rate of question closures recently for the Salesforce Marketing Cloud's MobilePush Android SDK and I have failed to get moderator assistance in getting the questions re-opened :)