# How can we stop ExactTarget and AMPScript questions being flagged for closure?

Tags: discussion, exacttarget, flagging

This is somewhat related to the question here:

- [Encouraging ExactTarget questions to be tagged](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/584/encouraging-exacttarget-questions-to-be-tagged)

Personally I have the `exacttarget` tag filtered out as I'm not in a position to be able to help people with ExactTarget questions, however occasionally I notice them coming into the review queue with close votes, and inevitably they end up closed.

Here is a recent example:

- [Issue parsing RSS feed in Exacttarget ampscript](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38591/only-use-blog-posts-from-the-last-week)

When this came into my review queue I voted to leave it open and added the `exacttarget` tag to try and ensure future reviewers didn't close it, however it still ended up closed when in my opinion it shouldn't be as it seems a perfectly valid question about AMPscript (or at least as valid as some of the Apex questions we end up with).

Here is another example:

- [exacttarget Automation studio : cannot schedule the Automation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33953/exacttarget-automation-studio-cannot-schedule-the-automation)

I guess my question is, could I have done more to stop the blog post related question from being closed?

Is there something we can do to raise awareness of the fact that ExactTarget and AMPscript questions are legitimate questions on SFSE?

Comment: Like you, I have them filtered and frequently edit questions to add the exacttarget tag to them when I recognize that's what they're about. Its a difficult situation for many of us who know very little about ExactTarget. I generally follow a "hands off" approach to those questions except I did vote to reopen an AmpScript related one a day or so ago that probably shouldn't have been closed to begin with. ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are some reviewers who don't always pay a lot of attention, to this and other things. I've even seen some vandalism/advertising things get passed reviews. **I personally don't think there's much else we can do than be alert for these scenario's and re-open when wrongly closed.**

You're actively participating, Im not sure if there's more you can do. **It's a community and collaboration, sometimes that may initially go wrong.**

I for instance changed the title of your first example to make it more obvious that it wasn't off-topic. It was still in the close review queue at the time, and I too didn't know what else to do. It's good to see that it didn't end up closed.

In terms of closing Exacttarget questions when they truly are off-topic, I find that quite hard without much knowledge of those technologies either. I usually skip them or follow Kelly J Andrews's vote/comments as he's an official representative of Exacttarget.

Comment: I agree, I usually follow suit with Kelly J Andrews, as I don't personally have enough knowledge to really know if it is or isn't off topic.

Comment: And now I want to learn ExactTarget. It only seems natural.